# What is Eulerian?

Tags: special-functions, q-analogs

I encountered an interesting function which is called "Eulerian" by the Wolfram's MathWorld:

$$\phi(q)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{k})$$

It is interesting because it seems that roots of any polynomial can be expressed in this function and elementary functions.

I want to know more about the properties of this function, where can I find the information?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function some sparse info

Comment: Btw, I found that in Mathematica it can be represented as $\operatorname{QPochhammer}[q^n]$

Answer (score 9):

One notable property of this function is [Euler's Pentagonal Number Theorem:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem)

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-x^k) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k x^{k(3k-1)/2}.$$

Here is a very interesting [paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0510/0510054v2.pdf) on the Pentagonal Number Theorem by Jordan Bell.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look up [Weierstrass factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) which plays a crucial role in complex analysis for writing functions as infinite products. It is a simple but powerful idea. Euler's famous proof of the [Basel's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) exploited this infinite product for $\sin(x)$.